# Timing multiple innerfade slideshows on the page

Tags: jquery, slideshow, timing

I've asked about this before but didn't really get anywhere.

I need to have three images displaying on a page, each of them looping through a set, but timed in sequence. This means that when the page loads three images display, after 2 seconds the first one changes, after a further 2 secs the second one, then the third, an then it would repeat endlessly.

I've used innerfade.js and here is a simple setup, but this doesn't have the time off-set.

```
<div id="header-img-1">
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/ggbg.gif" width="318" height="110" />
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/whizzkids.gif" width="318" height="110" />
</div>

<div id="header-img-2">
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/km.jpg" width="318" height="110" />
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/tuev.jpg" width="318" height="110" />
</div>

<div id="header-img-3">
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/rt_arch.jpg" width="318" height="110" />
<img src="http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/images/whizzkids.gif" width="318" height="110" />
</div>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(

function() {
$('#header-img-1').innerfade2({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    type: 'sequence',
    containerheight: '1em'
});

$('#header-img-2').innerfade2({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    type: 'sequence',
    containerheight: '1em'
});

$('#header-img-3').innerfade2({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    type: 'random_start',
    containerheight: '1em'
});
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/gFveN/

So #header-img-1 needs to fade 2 secs after page load, #header-img-2 adter 4 secs, and #header-img-3 after 6 secs, all of them fading every 6 seconds.

I'm not very Javascript literate, so I'm hoping for a kind soul to help me out with the correct code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The API-Description](https://github.com/wesbaker/jquery.innerFade) allows to add a parameter `startDelay`:

```
startDelay: Time before the first slide change (Default: '0')
```

so

```
$('#header-img-1').innerfade2({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    startDelay:2000,   // declare your initial delays here
    type: 'sequence',
    containerheight: '1em'
});
```

will do the trick.

EDIT: your initial version was too old, use the version i provided in the link above. See it working in [your modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/gFveN/2/). Beware the different naming of the function - `innerfade2` vs `innerFade`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post, Christoph. I hadn't noticed the startDelay option. It seems to work well with "type: 'sequence',". http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/2w8wT/ I wonder whether there is an easy way to  start the slide show at a random image. I've tried "type: 'random_start'," bu that doesn't seem to do it....

Comment: It looks like this plugin does not have the option to start with a random image. You could contact the author and ask for suhc a feature or implement a random number generator and hand that over to the init-function. You should start a new question when you need help with that. However, if my answer solved your initial question, mark the answer with the green checkmark to indicate to other people in the community that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank for your help here, and also pointing out marking the question as answered. I cannot see how to do that. I can sonly see how to mark that your answer was helpful.